# What will happen if my flight gets cancelled after my 90 days is up and I am already at the gate?

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

What will happen if I were to go to the airport on my last day of my Schengen visa, I get to the airport, and my flight is not canceled. I go through security and immigration. I get to my gate and my flight is canceled. Since I am through the gate and immigration am I still in the "Schengen Area"?

And would I be able to go to the main terminal?

What would happen to the exit stamp, since it is then unvalid?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because I am asking about after you get through security and have the exited stamp on your passport.

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference. The answer was that you should contact the border authorities immediately and surely that still applies.

Comment: There is always a leeway for such incidents. If the plane cannot get off the ground for some reason, you will be offered a chance to stay back and take the next available flight.

Comment: relevant : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_who_have_lived_at_airports  (ie, when some bad combination of events happens, you could end up stuck in the "international zone" ... better take a few days advance than try your luck ?)

Comment: That depends. Are you a citizen of Krakozhia?

Comment: Edited my question a bit. I forgot to ask that. but If that is off topic i will Revert it to original question.

Comment: Regarding the exit stamp, if your visa allows it, the logical solution is to simply give you another entry stamp. There is no rule against entering and leaving multiple times on the same day. But there is actually a procedure to cancel an exit stamp if need be (say a border guard made a genuine mistake for someone who has a single entry visa). And of course, as others have pointed out, in such an unusual situation, it's not unthinkable that border guards would simply ignore the rules and wave you through or stamp your passport even if your visa technically does not allow it.

Comment: Can you add that to your answer please? Because It is very hard to accept an answer. They are both very good. but not quite Answered.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Each airport and airline handles it differently.

I encountered it once and the airline provided accommodation at a nearby hotel.  Those of us who could enter the country did so.  Those that could not were escorted through immigration in a group and had their passports held.  The doorman at the hotel wouldn't let you out unless you had your passport.  The next day we were escorted back to the airport.

Comment: "The doorman at the hotel wouldn't let you out" what kind of authority did this doorman hold? Not that I would try to leave without a passport but if I did I wouldn't expect the doorman to be able to stop me.

Comment: I would not completely rule out some *ad hoc* solution like that (even without holding the passport, border guards could be tempted to stamp it and ignore the extra day for example) but I don't see any legal basis for it. Was it in the Schengen area?

Comment: @DasBeasto - A doorman has as much "authority" as a bouncer at a club or other security staff.  And if he has been instructed by Immigration to hold people there, he has the weight of the national government behind his "authority".

Comment: @Relaxed - no it was not in a Schengen country.  But if you are aware any EU or Schengen specific rules that prohibit this, feel free to provide links.

Comment: Perhaps the hotel was, in effect, serving as a temporary immigration detention center, and the doorman as a detention center guard.

Comment: @Tom The way EU law works, you would need a rule to *allow* it. By default, if you require a visa, you cannot enter without a visa and member states cannot arbitrarily ignore the Schengen regulations just because they feel like it. I detailed the rules designed to give them an out in my answer.

Comment: This is an answer to https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/40073/4188 and not the question at hand.

Comment: I think it's more likely the doorman simply informs you that you are not allowed to leave, and that if you insist on leaving there will be a phone call, the arrival of police or border guards, your arrest and banning from the country.

Comment: @Tom And what bouncer has the authority to detain me against my will? A bouncer's job is to control who comes in and remove people who need to be removed, not to prevent people from leaving. A hotel doorman can do nothing more than phone the police and say, "He went thattaway."

Comment: @Relaxed I would have thought one of the options for an EU country has to be to detain the alien at an off-airport location. Some airports close at night, or do not have facilities to detain people overnight.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's certainly an option if you formally refuse entry but that would seem like an incredibly harsh treatment. My money is on a temporary visa of some kind or just ignoring the rules.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - If you or any of the other nitpickers don't think is was legal, so be it.  I simply related what happened to me.  If it happens in the future to you and you want to argue with airline staff that it is illegal, feel free to do such.  And while you sit in the airport chairs all night long, i will enjoy the bed they provide me with.

Comment: @Tom All I'm (and, I think, we are) saying is that the claim that the hotel doorman was told not to let you leave is not strictly true. I've no idea where you get the idea that I'd prefer to sit in an airport lounge than sleep in a hotel bed. I certainly never said anything like htat.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I was there, I saw what happened, I heard what was said to the inconvenienced flyers (I was one of the inconvenienced).  And I know that the doorman did not let people out, as I had to go buy diapers for another passenger because they were not allowed to leave (I was amongst the folks who were able to clear immigration on our own).  But perhaps you know what happened to me better than I do .....

Comment: @DavidRicherby indeed. As a not-so-funny related note, I was once at a club in my own country. The bouncers would not let us leave if we won't spend at least X € in drinks. I had to call the military police at night to have them extract me from the club. :D There is no way a bouncer has legal authority to detain a person unless (maybe) this person is committing a crime that can result in arrest by a private citizen (varies by country).

Comment: A bouncer has any authority given him/her by his government.

Comment: I think the doorman has the authority to say "you can't leave" and if you say "Ok then, I'll stay in the hotel" then everything is fine. If not, he then has the authority to say, "no, you really can't leave, and if you leave I'll have to call the police", but that's about it. If it's a good hotel then they will get things for you that you need to avoid the need to leave.

Answer (score 31):

I've directly observed this before, in Germany.

Passengers who needed visas due to *force majeure* were issued 24-hour Schengen visas at the consular office inside the Frankfurt airport.

There is a duplicate answer with citations from the Schengen Code [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89013/what-happens-if-my-flight-out-of-the-schengen-area-is-cancelled-on-the-last-day).

Comment: +1, thanks for the first-hand report, very useful! There is a slight difference in this question, the OP has already exhausted the 90-day maximum stay allowance, which would technically prevent Germany from extending the visa under article 33.

Comment: Oh I see that someone edited that out!

Comment: @Relaxed It's quite possible that the border guards will simply ignore the rule and issue the visa anyway

Answer (score 29):

In a sense you still are, you are on the territory of a Schengen country, its law fully applies, if you did anything that would justify it, you could be arrested by the police, etc. The airport, even the area after the exit passport check is not some sort of extraterritorial area out of reach of the country's laws.

That said, if you stay airside in the sterile departure area, I don't see how you could possibly be deemed to have breached the conditions of your visa. You already have an exit stamp with the proper date and would not have any problems the next time you applied for a visa or enter the Schengen area. If the airports has such facilities, you should press the airlines to offer you lounge access or an airside hotel room to wait for the next flight.

Now, if you need to go through the passport check again, say, to spend the night outside of the airport or catch a plane at another airport in the vicinity, things become more complicated. There is a provision to [extend a Schengen visa (article 33 of the visa code)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89013/what-happens-if-my-flight-out-of-the-schengen-area-is-cancelled-on-the-last-day) if you have a serious reason but my reading of the regulation is that this is in principle only possible if the new stay would not lead you to exceed the global 90-day limit for short stays in the Schengen area.

If someone needs to stay longer than that, member states still have the possibility to issue a “limited territoriality visa” (article 25) and they may in any case issue a visa at the border (article 35). Both of these are intended as exceptional procedures but the authorities have some leeway in judging what's an exceptional case. Combining articles 25 and 35 would therefore seem to be a fully legal way to grant you some more time in the country where you presently are, at the cost of a bit of paperwork and possibly a fee.

I can also imagine that some border guards would be confused about all this and I am not entirely sure that it would happen smoothly.

Comment: Once the OP has passed immigration he's out of the country for immigration purposes. The worst that can happen is he won't be allowed out of the sterile area. In that case it's the airline's responsibility to provide him accommodation and food-.

Comment: @greatone Isn't that what I just wrote?

Comment: Depending on the airport that could be amazingly crazy. Berlin (Tegel) has sterile areas that serve only ONE GATE - so he would have pretty much have to exit it for the next boarding to be processed, and there is like a 99% chance the replacement flight would start from another gate.

Comment: But this is handled by security or the airline. You could be put also in an outside hotel and still considered in "sterile" area. The airline will organize stuffs for you.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Says who?

Comment: A possible justification for a member state to tolerate an overrun of the 90/180 day rule in this case would be the Article 6(5)(c) of the Borders Code: _"third-country nationals who do not fulfil one or more of the conditions laid down in paragraph 1 may be authorised by a Member State to enter its territory on humanitarian grounds, on grounds of national interest or because of international obligations. ..."_ There is at least a case for it being "humanitarian" to allow someone stranded at an airport through no fault of their own to remain until they have an opportunity to leave.

Comment: Another possible justification would be that the _definition_ of the 90/180 rule in Article 6(1) reads: _"For **intended** stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period ..."_ (emphasis added). If the traveler didn't at any time _intend_ to stay beyond 90 days but were forced to do so by circumstances out of his control, it is not obvious that the rule actually applies.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Article 6(5)(c) might apply, since the visa requirement is referred to in paragraph 1 and the Borders code could conceivably be used to waive it entirely in this situation (although I doubt this was the intent behind this provision) but article 6(1) is moot, as we are talking about a visa holder who just exhausted their visa. The visa requirement is the main hurdle here and that's the rule I discuss in my answer.

Comment: @TomTom Does Berlin (Tegel) even handle international departures *at all*? (by which I mean outside the Schengen area, not outside Germany) When I was there I had to stopover in Munich before leaving Europe.

Comment: @immibis: it does, though not many. I've flown Tegel - Moscow and back.

Comment: @immibis They try to sort it out, but with Berlin central airport having the unique selling point of not working... well... It is an OLD airport - no idea who came up with that idiotic design. These days there are few, but yes, there are non-schengen flights from there.

Comment: "the area after the exit passport check is not some sort of extraterritorial area" ... while true, it's actually irrelevant.  Visas grant leave to enter the country... to use an analogy, if you're camped out on my front lawn you're on my property but you're not in my house.  The edge of the lawn is the territorial boundary but my front door is border control.

Comment: @immibis There are about 18 non-stop flights per day to London airports from TXL. There are also daily flights to New York, Dublin, Abu Dhabi, Istanbul. Plus non daily flights to Los Angeles, San Francisco, Toronto, Newark, Ankara, ... and occasional charter flights to Beijing, Baghdad, Erbil, .... I don't know where you were trying to go exactly? :)

Comment: @Kaithar In a similar way that you could evict trespassers from your lawn, the country in question may, or may not, allow some people into its "international zone" for transit purposes without a visa. The country doesn't have to do this. Many people will require visas simply to land at the airport even if they don't intend to enter that country.

Comment: @Calchas quite so, though I think most countries will allow people to enter the international zone without a visa for the purpose of a connecting flight.  Generally speaking a Visa is better thought of as permission to remain rather than permission to enter since refugees, rescuees and lost travellers may all find themselves in situations where they have to enter a country before they can formally receive permission to do so.  It would be a bit problematic if people needed a Visa before the coast guard would let them off the boat.

Comment: @Kaithar We agree, but I would add, sometimes you need a visa just to transit through a country's airports as an international-international traveller. If you are travelling on a Syrian passport, most countries won't let you enter their airports under any circumstances (except as a refugee---I'm just looking at travellers, not refugees). If you have an Afghan passport, most countries will require a transit visa for you to transit through their airports.

Answer (score 5):

This has happened to me personally, you either get a 24 hour temp visa or they escort to a hotel at the airport and back again the next day, both happened to me, FWIW other countries mostly do the same it happened to me in china and in Australia as well, as long as you go with the airline staff to immigrations they will sort you out

Answer (score -14):

Ok first of all while leaving a country you do not go through immigration you go through security check. Big difference.

The security check is to check for hazardous materials in your possession before you get on a plane.

Immigration is to check for your visa and stamp on your passport that marks the date of entry into the country. Which basically says you're here legally.

That being said:

Airport terminals have different rules. Some require transit visas if you're changing terminals as you will be leaving the international zone. Some don't need you to have a transit visa as long as your departure gate is in the same terminal.

If your flight gets canceled and if you're told you will be given a hotel to stay, it is your duty to mention to them that your visa will expire as of 00:00 midnight.

You will either be given a transit visa for 3 to 4 days or you will be taken to a waiting lounge that has beds so you can sleep. Use airline lounges restroom to shower etc. I have had a 21hr layover in France and they said since I have a residence permit in Germany I can go out if I wish or stay in the lounge.

EU laws are relaxed unlike the US or UK but they wouldn't let you leave an area by that I mean they won't hold you hostage it's just that to leave that area you have to go through immigration. The route is designed that way.

Without a valid visa, you will not be allowed to leave the terminal and you will be sent back to where you were so you can catch a flight and go home.

Comment: "while leaving a country you do not go through immigration you go through security check. Big difference.". **Wrong**, in most countries you do clear Immigration on Exit. The UK and the US are among a few exceptions

Comment: @Crazydre I guess technically you could call it "Emigration" instead of "Immigration" :)

Comment: @Crazydre: add Canada to the list, but I agree that the list is very short.

Comment: @Crazydre: Interesting! I'm Canadian, and I thought that was the rule, not the exception, and it clears up a related question I had.

Comment: @Crazydre Wait, so you mean there are other countries besides the UK, US, and Canada??

Comment: @Mehrdad Ireland and Mexico, for example